# How to enumerate all possible associations given a relational schema?

Tags: redux, foreign-keys, schema, code-generation, entity-relationship

**Some background**

I'm working on a data-intensive UI where state is stored in a Redux container. Anyone who has ever touched Redux knows there's a lot of repetitive boilerplate to be written in the form of reducers, actions, action creators, selectors (analogous to queries), and so on.

There's no fun in writing these, especially when there's a lot of entity types and accompanying relationships involved.

Therefore, the idea is to devise a relational schema together with a code generator to which the heavy lifting can be outsourced.

**Problem**

Given a (hypothetical) relational schema like the following:

```
const schema = {
  book: {
    attributes: ["id", "name", "subGenreId"],
    foreignKeys: [
      { fromAttribute: "subGenreId", toEntity: "subGenre", toAttribute: "id" }
    ]
  },

  mainGenre: {
    attributes: ["id", "name"]
  },

  subGenre: {
    attributes: ["id", "name", "mainGenreId"],
    foreignKeys: [
      { fromAttribute: "mainGenreId", toEntity: "mainGenre", toAttribute: "id" }
    ]
  },

  author: {
    attributes: ["id", "name"]
  },

  book_author: {
    attributes: ["bookId", "authorId"],
    foreignKeys: [
      { fromAttribute: "bookId", toEntity: "book", toAttribute: "id" },
      { fromAttribute: "authorId", toEntity: "author", toAttribute: "id" }
    ]
  },

  seller: {
    attributes: ["id", "name"]
  },

  seller_book: {
    attributes: ["sellerId", "bookId"],
    foreignKeys: [
      { fromAttribute: "sellerId", toEntity: "seller", toAttribute: "id" },
      { fromAttribute: "bookId", toEntity: "book", toAttribute: "id" }
    ]
  }
};
```

The goal is to (computationally, of course) generate selectors along these lines (probably forgot a few):

"direct" relationships:

- `books` by `subGenre` id
- `mainGenre` by `subGenre` id
- `subGenre` by `book` id
- `subGenres` by `mainGenre` id

many-to-many relationships (omitted the junction tables themselves):

- `authors` by `book` id
- `books` by `author` id
- `books` by `seller` id
- `sellers` by `book` id

"distant" relationships (this is where it gets interesting):

- `authors` by `mainGenre` id
- `authors` by `seller` id
- `authors` by `subGenre` id
- `books` by `mainGenre` id
- `mainGenre` by `book` id
- `mainGenres` by `author` id
- `mainGenres` by `seller` id
- `sellers` by `author` id
- `sellers` by `mainGenre` id
- `sellers` by `subGenre` id
- `subGenres` by `author` id
- `subGenres` by `seller` id

There are also more complex (e.g. circular) relationships like co-authors, but I don't mind manually writing code for these when the need arises.

How would one go about enumerating these associations between entities? Are there pre-existing solutions? I can imagine graph traversal being involved, but perhaps it is better solved using methods I'm not yet aware of.